# places not found using google places api in iOS

Tags: ios, search, google-places-api

I am trying to show nearby places with selected types 
types - Bar, Cafe, ATM etc

I have created project on developer console.
enable API (google places api, google map sdk, direction api)

I have created iOS api keys but Api key not working. I got this error message

> This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API
>   key. Request received from IP address 114.143.244.10, with empty
>   referer

When I tried browser api key I got this error

> This API project is not authorized to use this API.
>   Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn
>   more: https://code.google.com/apis/console

I am using this url

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@",
    currentCentre.latitude,
    currentCentre.longitude,
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currenDist],
    googleType,
    kGOOGLE_API_KEY
    ];
```

I didn't get what is the problem.

Comment: can you help me for google api. because google api is more efficient than MapKit as per my reading @0yeoj

Comment: try to activate places api in your project settings on google developer console page

Comment: I have did that already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable to this api **Google Places API Web Service** & **Google Places API for iOS**  in the APIs Console

Refer to this document....

**Google Places API Web Service**

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search

Comment: I have tried both api key with this url but I got same error https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&key=API_KEY

Comment: Check your issue: - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/m96hDesC_Tg

Answer (score 1):

Please Check Your All API are Enable On The Google Developer Console

**Step 1**  Go to Developer Console

**Step 2**  API Manager ==> API Library ==> Google Maps APIs ==> More

**Step 3**  And Enable ==> Google Places API Web Service 
            (AutoComplete and Seaching)

**Step 4**  Done Enjoy (^_^) ALl Is Done !!!!

NOTE:- Make Sure Your API KEY is Proper and Created Okay ....

Answer (score 0):

I think i know your problem now, it possible that you missed a step..

the steps are suppose to be:

1) Go to Developer Console https://code.google.com/apis/console/

2) In the Credentials, under Public API Access , Create New key

3) Select the server key from the option.

4) Enter your IP Address on the field and if you have more ip addresses, you can just add on every single line.NOTE: Enter the IP Address only when you want to use it for your testing purpose. Else leave the IP Address section blank.

5) Once you are done, click create and your new Server Key will be generated and you can then add that server key to your URL.

use it like:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=[lat],[lon]&radius=[radius]&key=kGOOGLE_API_KEY&sensor=true`

or from the tutorial that you are using..

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=[lat],[lon]&radius=[radius]&types=[type]&key=kGOOGLE_API_KEY&sensor=true`

as you can see `&sensor=true` is the last parameter..(don't trust anything on the internet).. hahaha..

everything must have been working if you have followed, carefully.. i suggest do it from the top.. hahaha.. Lols.. you'll know and learn what's missing/forgotten, and that'll help you be a better person.. Lols.. Good luck sir.. :)

Comment: but I am following this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit

Comment: I have followed your step I got same error. also I have tried this url in browser with api key I got same error.    {
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: I have added my api key in google doc textsearch url @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&key=API_KEY" and try it using search browser but I got same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this library https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTGooglePlacesAPI with your key and let me know.